# json2html from json file (python on server side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json

I have the python code where I pass the json file

```
def home():
    with open('file.json', 'a+') as f:
        return render_template('index.html', json_data=f.read())
```

The file look like this

```
{"hosts": [{"shortname": "serv1", "ipadr": "10.0.0.1", "longname": "server1"}, {"shortname": "serv2", "ipadr": "10.0.0.2", "longname": "server2"}]}
```

On the client side, I wrote this code

```
<table id="placar" class="table table-condensed  table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>shortname</th>
          <th>longname</th>
          <th>ipadress</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
var data = {{ json_data }}


var transform = {
    tag: 'tr',
    children: [{
        "tag": "td",
            "html": "${shortname}"
    }, {
        "tag": "td",
            "html": "${ipadr}"
    }, {
        "tag": "td",
            "html": "${longname}"
    }]
};

$('#placar > tbody ').json2html(data, transform);
</script>
```

But it doesn't work with my file, if write the simple array it works perfectly. Can anyone say what I did wrong, pass the file or create a table?

Comment: `dmp=Json.dumps(Any_python_dict)`, `with open('file.json', 'r') as f:` ignore `EOF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try

```
import json
def home():
  with open('file.json', 'a+') as f:
    return render_template('index.html', json.dumps(f.read()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna want to transform the data.hosts rather than just the data object like so

```
$('#placar > tbody ').json2html(data.hosts, transform);
```

so all together you'll have

```
var data = {"hosts": [{"shortname": "serv1", "ipadr": "10.0.0.1", "longname": "server1"}, {"shortname": "serv2", "ipadr": "10.0.0.2", "longname": "server2"}]};

var transform = {
    tag: 'tr',
    children: [{
        "tag": "td",
            "html": "${shortname}"
    }, {
        "tag": "td",
            "html": "${ipadr}"
    }, {
        "tag": "td",
            "html": "${longname}"
    }]
};

$('#placar > tbody ').json2html(data.hosts, transform);
```